# How do I see the calls made by a website to the window object in browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension

I have a third party extension that injects an object on the `window` object. A specific website makes calls to this object. I want to capture the calls that the website makes to this object. How can I do that?

Below is sample call made by website to the third party extension.

```
const value = await window.thirdpartyextension.doThis(a, b);
```

I want to be able to capture this call in realtime (`doThis`, `a` and `b`).
Goal is to create an extension for personal use that will do some work when these calls are made.
Either chrome or firefox is fine.

Any pointers (with slight code or example) on how to start capturing these calls will be very helpful for me.

Let me know if something is unclear about the question.

Comment: what do you mean by "capture"?

Comment: @Bravo I mean capture or be able to see the call (function name, arguments). I have added an example in question.

Comment: you've added an example of the function being called - you haven't added an example of exactly what information you want to "capture" - i.e. given the example call, what is the result you wish to achieve with your extension -

Comment: I want to capture the function name that is called "doThis" and the arguments (a, b) and use that to do some other work.

Comment: @Bravo thank you, seems that is what i wanted to do. So can I just inject this into the `window` and it will start taking control (over the target)? Sorry, I'm very new to javascript.

Comment: I removed a comment, since Proxy won't help - didn't realise what you wanted until you spelled it out :p

Answer (score -1):

One approach is to constantly check if the object has been attached to the `window` by verifying if a determined property has changed. To perform so, you can use the built-in [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) in order to define an interval that runs continuously to check if any changes had been detected. It's like polling but asynchronously.

```js
function doWhenChange() {
  alert("Added property fooBar to window: " + window.fooBar)
}

let delay = 1e3 // 1 sec
let interval = setInterval(() => {
  if (window.fooBar === 'fooValue') {
    doWhenChange()
    clearInterval(interval)
  } else {
    console.log("Nothing...")
  }
}, delay)

setTimeout(() => {
  window.fooBar = 'fooValue'
}, 3e3)
```